# Operator distributivity in expressions - syntactic sugar

Tags: operators

When writing boolean expressions out, you often have to use something of the type:

```
A == any of B1, ..., Bn
C < all of D1, ..., Dm
```

But in code you have to use expanded forms:

```
A == B1 or ... or A == Bn
C < D1 and ... and C < Dm
```

That looks, to me, like *any of* and *all of* are simply the distributed form of *or* and *and*. That made me wonder if you can apply distributivity to operators in some way that compilers/interpretors can understand. For the above example, say, something like this:

```
A == B1 +_or ... +_or Bn
C < D1 +_and ... +_and Dm
```

Essentially, taking operators as relations, it should work something like this:

```
R1(A, distributive_R2(B1, ... , Bn)) becomes
R2(R1(A, B1), ... , R1(A, Bn))
```

This could apply to more than just booleans:

```
X / Y1 +_+ ... +_+ Yn becomes
X/Y1 + ... + X/Yn
```

Of course, my `+_` prefix may not be the ideal syntax; I'm sure there's better ones out there. Nevertheless, this strikes me as being possibly quite useful and understandable. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not 100% sure, since your "syntax" is a bit unusual, but this seems to be similar to the 'fold' function you find in many languages (especially functional languages) where you apply a single function on all elements in a list like `foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3]` would sum a list or `foldl (&&) True [True, False, True]` would apply AND on all elements of a bool list. You have this in many languages or could implement easy enough as long as you have higher order functions.

Answer (score 3):

**1. I don't like the syntax**

`A == B1 or ... or A == Bn` is not obvious. It is for simple forms, but those simple forms are rare. For example, there is no need to write:

```
A == 1 or ... or A == 10
```

when you can simply write:

```
A >= 1 and A <= 10
```

If you enumerate through the sequence, the syntax won't help neither:

```
Set = [ 4, 7, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1 ]
A == Set[0] or ... or A == Set[Set.Length]
```

is too verbose.

Also, what would:

```
A == 1 or ... and A == 10
```

mean? If this is illegal, how an IDE would prevent it? Why forcing the developer to type the same word twice?

Readability should be your concern too. `C < D1 +_and ... +_and Dm` in your question is already difficult to understand. I can't imagine a piece of code which combines several ranges.

**2. `in` and ranges in SQL and Ada**

The easier syntax would be the one which is already used in SQL for keywords and in Ada and Matlab for ranges:

```
A in 1..10
```

or:

```
A in Set
```

Some SQL variants also use `between`:

```
A between 1 and 10
```

I largely prefer Ada syntax `1..10`, which is extremely explicit and shorter to write. The `and` keyword makes the reader think about a boolean operation, not a range. Without knowing the syntax, some developers will also be tempted to write either:

```
A between 1, 10
```

or:

```
A between(1, 10)
```

The SQL/Ada syntax is nice when it comes to searching a value in a set or a range, but not when it comes to verifying that an expression is true for any value of a sequence. I don't know if those languages have constructs allowing that.

**3. C# world, as a side note**

Note that in C#, which uses some paradigms from functional programming and has lambda expressions, your suggested syntax would be written this way:

Searching for a value in a sequence:

```
var isInList = sequence.Contains(value);
```

or:

```
var isInList = sequence.Any(a => a == value);
```

Verifying that en expression is valid for any element of a sequence:

```
var trueForAll = sequence.All(a => a > 0);
```

Filtering:

```
var positiveOnly = sequence.Where(a => a > 0);
```

This is not the best syntax ever, and I largely prefer the one which is inspired by SQL/Ada, but it gives you some ideas about how your problem is solved in different languages.

You can use this syntax to create your own, with specific language keywords. Something like:

```
A in Set              # Verifies that Set contains A.
B in 1..10            # Verifies that 1 ≤ B ≤ 10.
C > 0 for any Set     # Verifies that all elements of Set are positive.
D <> 0 for any 1..10  # Verifies that none of the values between 1 and 10 are equal to zero.
```